# How convert php line into javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

How can i convert this php-part into javascript function.

```
<li><a href="<?php if($path) {echo '/index.php#products';}else{echo 'javascript:void';} ?>" onclick="smoothScroll('products');">PRODUCTS</a></li>
```

Comment: Sorry what means 42?

Comment: It is a reference to a movie called "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", which  states that the meaning of life and "the answer to life the universe and everything" is 42, which basically is never explained. So the answer "42"  and the reason you're getting downvotes is because it's not clear what you want to do, what you've tried, why you're doing it (what you want to achieve) and the fact that you cannot "convert" server-side code to client-side code without knowing the context.

Comment: ))) what a funny place))))) thank you, but i am pretty sure that you Do can put some js (if-else) condition there. i just do't know what can i use instead of ' $path'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```
(window.location.pathname + window.location.hash) == 'index.php#products' ? 'index.php#products' : 'javascript.void'
```

[window.location / W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)